# Join table of foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have two tables, `groups` and `users` and I am trying to do things like:

1. Is a user pending their membership (if a group has a private setting and the user must be verified first)
2. When did the user join the group

etc.

For this reason, I am wondering if it is considered a valid choice to make a new table, something like `groups_users` which has a primary key that I completely ignore, but it has foreign keys `user_id` and `group_id`, and then fields like `is_admin`, `is_pending`, `joined_on`, etc.

Or, is there another way to do this that does not involve making such a table?

Comment: A third table sounds reasonable.

Comment: thanks for the reply!  what is the "correct" definition for such a table?  I am trying to improve my database skills.  Thanks

Comment: Another way would be to in users table to create set of columns dedicated for each group. Definitely not the way to go. I think you should look up for "bridge table" definition. This would describe functionality of such table. This allows to create many-to-many relationship. User can be a member of many groups & one group can have many members.

Comment: cool!  thank you.  i was searching google for this the whole time, I guess I should have searched for many to many relationship table.  thanks!

Comment: As to the primary key: You can make `user_id` + `group_id` the primary key. Or you can have the table without a primary key. Or you can add an id and make that the primary key. These are all valid options. Anyway, if you don't make `user_id` + `group_id` the primary key, you should still make them unique (i.e. add a unique constraint on them to the table).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks!  can you please explain what you mean by the first sentence?  "make user_id + group_id the primary key"?  How do you make sure you don't get a repeat pair?

Comment: Primary key values are by definition unique, i.e. you can't have any repeated pairs.

Comment: A primary key can consist of more than one column. The columns in a primary key are implicitly non-null and unique. If you decide not to make `user_id` + `group_id` the primary key, you should still make them not nullable and add a unique constraint on them. They are not *called* primary key then, but essentially it's the same. And so it must be, because it is the combination of these two fields that make for a record in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just looking this solutions...i am implementation of this schema of few projects

[image]

Comment: Good, but you should add some columns to `groups_users` to supports what the question asked. For example: `created_date`, `joined_date` and etc.

Comment: Yes, just show that example, developer can add additional columns.